# How to return default value based on some condition in typegoose property?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typegoose

I have following type in typescript model class

```
 @ApiModelPropertyOptional()
  @prop({
    _id: false,
    default: condition ? default_value : empty_value),
  })
  complexType?: ComplexType;
```

When I try to return **default** value based on some condition it is not working as expected. Can you please suggest the solution here?

Can you please give me an example to return default value based on some condition?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [function as the default](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions), mongoose will automatically execute it and the return value will then be used

```
  @prop({
    _id: false,
    default: () => condition ? default_value : empty_value,
  })
```

if the condition is based on some other value on the model, you can use `this` to access all properties (This requires the function to not be an arrow function)